# What was given on Mt. Sinai at each of the 40-day intervals

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, pentateuch-chumash, oral-torah, kabbalat-hatorah, aseres-hadibros

It's known that Moshe was on the mountain for 120 days and nights total, although I personally am not sure exactly what was given when.

(I'm aware of this question [How is the story of the Torah being given told in the Torah itself?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38772/how-is-the-story-of-the-torah-being-given-told-in-the-torah-itself?noredirect=1&lq=1), but this is not a dupe since I'm just asking what exactly was given when).

As far as I remember, Moshe went up for the first 40 days and nights to receive the "written Torah" and the tablets, then he went down, smashed them etc.. then the next day (I think?) he went back up for 40 days and nights to pray to Hashem for forgiveness, then I don't remember what happened, if he was given the Oral law right then, or later, but I'm pretty sure in the middle 40 days and nights he didn't in fact get the 2nd tablets, since that was later (but I'm not really sure), so IDK what he got after praying for 40 days and nights.

And then I don't know if he then came down right then and then went back up, but I'm pretty sure that, one way or another, he spent ANOTHER 40 days and nights, and I think I heard that he was receiving the Oral law then.

As you can see, I'm having some basic trouble with the timeline of what exactly he got at Mount Sinai and when. Here's the question basically:

**First 40 days and nights:**: Did he get only tablets or also the written Torah (up until that point), and did he receive any of the Oral Law at that point?

**Second set of 40 days and nights**: How long after the first 40 days and nights did he wait before going back up, and (I think he was praying the whole time but) what did he get at the end of this section? Did he get the 2nd set of tablets at this point, or later? Did he receive any of the Oral law or Written Torah at this point?

**Third set of 40 days and nights**: How long after the previous set did he wait before going back up, or did he just stay up there for 80 consecutive days and nights? What did he get exactly at the end of them, is it at this point that he received the second set of tablets, and what part of the Oral Law (if any) did he receive at this point?

I just wanted to clarify the narritive

Answer (score 0):

The three sets of 40 days were one after the other starting on/about 6/7 Sivan right after God spoke to the Jews on Sinai.

After the first 40 days--when Moshe came down and smashed the first tablets--the next day he went up for 40 days. Then he came back down, and the next day he went up for the third 40 days, culminating on Yom Kippur.

At the end of the first 40 days he came with the first tablets. At the end of the 3rd 40 days he came with the second tablets.